# Even solutions for a second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, cauchy-problem, geometric-realization

I need a check on the following exercise, especially a help in the second point, which I am not able to solve

> Consider the ode $$-u'' +u = u^3$$
>
> Given that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$: $$\frac{1}{2}|u'(t)|^2 - \frac{1}{2}|u(t)|^2 + \frac{1}{4}|u(t)|^4=C$$  with $C \in \mathbb{R}$, show that
>
> - if $\lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty} u(t)=0$ $(\star)$, then $C=0$.
> - Every **even** solution $u$ for which $(\star)$ holds is such that $|u(0)|^2=2$ or $u(0)=0$
> - Show that there are exactly three **even** solutions to the ODE for which $(\star)$ holds.

---

- From the asymptot theorem, if the limit is equal to a constant, then $$\lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty} |u'(t)|=0$$

From $$\frac{1}{2}|u'(t)|^2 - \frac{1}{2}|u(t)|^2 + \frac{1}{4}|u(t)|^4=C$$ taking the limit it follows that $$\lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty} 0.5 |u'(t)|=C=0$$ hence $C=0$.

- **Here's the most difficult point for me**. I know that $u(t)=u(-t)$ and $\frac{d}{dt} u(-t) = - u'(-t)$. I'd like to use the identity above and the fact that $C=0$, since the solution satisfies ($\star$), to obtain $$\frac{1}{2} |u(t)|^2 \Bigl( \frac{1}{2}|u(t)|^2 - 1 \Bigr)=0$$ and hence, plugging in $t=0$, I find $$|u(0)|^2 = 2$$ or $$|u(0)|=0$$

but I don't know how to do that.

- I think this point is trivial:

Recasting the system as a first order ODE, I have the vector function $$F(y,y')=[y',y-y^3]^T$$ which is clearly $C^{\infty}$. Therefore, I have at least local existence and uniqueness. So I have just shown above that if I have an even solution, for which $\star$ holds, then I can have $u(0)= \pm \sqrt{2}$ or $u(0)=0$, therefore  *three possibile initial data*, hence three possibile solutions.

---

**Any hint or help in the second point is highly appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $u'(t) = -u'(-t)$, plugging $t=0$ gives
$$u'(0) = - u'(0) \Rightarrow 2u'(0) = 0\Rightarrow u'(0) = 0.$$

From the first part we have $C=0$. Thus
$$\frac{1}{2}|u'(t)|^2 - \frac{1}{2}|u(t)|^2 + \frac{1}{4}|u(t)|^4=0.$$
Putting $t=0$ and use $u'(0) = 0$ gives
$$ - \frac{1}{2}|u(0)|^2 + \frac{1}{4}|u(0)|^4=0.$$
Solving the above gives $u(0) = 0$ or $|u(0)|^2 = 2$.

For your last part, we have the uniqueness theorem, but you have to be a bit careful on the initial conditions: since you transform it into a first order system, an initial condition is a pair $(u(0), u'(0))$ instead of just $u(0)$. So the three initials conditions are

$$\begin{pmatrix} u(0) \\  u'(0)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\  0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt 2 \\  0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt 2 \\  0\end{pmatrix}$$
instead of just $\pm \sqrt 2, 0$.

Comment: Yes I was too sloppy on the last point @ArcticChar , but I was exactly thinking about that. Thanks (you surelt wanted to wirite $\pm \sqrt{2}$.

One last question: Is it fine the local uniqueness part? When I have a second order ODE I'm always a bit scared at this point,because I have those vector functions. But if I show that each component is $C^{\infty}$ in an open neigbourhood of the initial data I'm fine, right?

Comment: Yes. As long as you show that both components have continuous derivatives around those three points in my answers, then you can use the uniqueness theorem (In this situation those two component are smooth everywhere so the checking is easy). @andereBen

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!